# Check if textboxes have the same content

Tags: textbox, google-apps-script, iteration

I want to check if the textboxes created like this:

```
(function(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        app.add(app.createLabel(arr[i] + " mail"));
        app.add(app.createTextBox().setName(arr[i]));
    }
})(["first", "second", "third"]);
```

have the same contents? I was looking for something like getElementByTagname or or getTextboxes, but there are no such functions.

So how to iterate thvrough them and show a label if they are all equal?

Comment: some context might help.  show some definition for 'app'?  Looks like this is a UiInstance from UiApp, but please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access any widget values you need to add them as a callback element (or a parent panel) to the server handler that will process them. The values of each widget are populated on a parameter passed to the handler function and can be referenced by the widget `name` (that you already set).

You don't need to `setId` as suggested on another answer. Unless you want to do something with the widget itself (and not its value). e.g. change its text or hide it, etc.

```js
var textBoxes = ["first", "second", "third"];

function example() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  textBoxes.forEach(function(name){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(name + " mail"));
    panel.add(app.createTextBox().setName(name));
  });
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Example Label').setId('label').setVisible(false));

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('btnHandler').addCallbackElement(panel);
  panel.add(app.createButton('Click').addClickHandler(handler));

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app.add(panel));
}

function btnHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(),
      allEqual = true;
  for( var i = 1; i < textBoxes.length; ++i )
    if( e.parameter[textBoxes[i-1]] !== e.parameter[textBoxes[i]] ) {
      allEqual = false; break;
    }
  app.getElementById('label').setVisible(allEqual);
  return app;
}
```

Notice that `ServerHandlers` do not run instantly, so it may take a few seconds for the label to show or hide after you click the button.

Comment: I liked the forEach, but after that it seems you are comparing the fields by hand - e.parameter.first. I was looking for any suggestion how to iterate the fiels. Now they are only 3, but if they are more?!? How to pass through all of them?

Comment: Just do the same thing. Create the array (or place it on global scope) and iterate. I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: By the way, since you're new here. You should check an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one. Voting is also another nice feature.

Comment: @ Henrique Abreu now the answer is solving my problem. The change from 'first' to indexing clears the things. It will be accepted.

Comment: @Henrique,Hi, I'm kind of intrigued by a part of your code * textBoxes.forEach(function(name){*  I don't know this construction...could you briefly explain how it works if ever you have time?  Thx , cheers.Serge

Comment: @Serge this is an array method, although it's not autocompleted it works fine. It iterates through the array for you, in order, and provide some parameters to the callback function. The first one is the element. You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

When you create the textboxes, assign each one an id using [`setId(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textbox#setId).
When you want to obtain their reference later, you can then use [`getElementById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#getElementById).

Here is an example:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createTextBox().setId("tb1").setText("the original text"));
  app.add(app.createButton().setText("Change textbox").addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("myHandler")));
  return app;
}

function myHandler() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById("tb1").setText("new text: in handler");
  return app;
}
```